# How can I make my Visual Studio Code terminal compile my c code? (I already have the C extension)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to compile in the terminal my C code in Visual Studio Code. How can I do this?

This is how it should look like:

[image: This is an image of what it should look like]

But in my Visual Studio Code it looks like this:[image]

Comment: Do you have a compiler?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: well, try [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_build-helloworldcpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if you've installed a C compiler.
If not, consider browsing [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

I recommend you using Mingw, quite easy to install.
You can find many videos online to install this compiler on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ubfgi4NoTPk)

With all of this installed, it should perfectly work after a reboot of your computer! :)

Comment: Thank you very much!